# $\int_G dx^1\wedge \cdots \wedge dx^k$ where $G$ is the graph of a function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, manifolds, pullback

I would like to evaluate $\int_G dx^1\wedge \cdots \wedge dx^k$ where $G \subset \mathbb{R}^{k+1}$ is the graph of the function $F : [0,1]^k\to \mathbb{R}$.

Intuitively, I think this is the "volume" of $F$ over $[0,1]^k$. But when I expanded it out, my calculation showed it is something else. If I write $G(x^1, \cdots, x^k) = (x^1, \cdots, x^k, f(x^1,\cdots,x^k))$, then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_G dx^1\wedge \cdots \wedge dx^k &= \int_{[0,1]^k} G^*(dx^1\wedge \cdots \wedge dx^k) \\
&= \int_{[0,1]^k} (G^*dx^1) \wedge \cdots \wedge(G^* dx^k) \\
&= \int_{[0,1]^k} dx^1\wedge \cdots \wedge dx^k = 1^k = 1
\end{aligned}
$$
Somehow $f$ does not come into play here. Can someone point out where I did something wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: $G^*$ isn't necessarily the identity

Comment: I evaluated $G^*(x^i) = d(G^i \circ G) = dx^i$. Is this step wrong?

Comment: where does $F$ enter into play?

Comment: Well, I think if $G$ is graph of $F$, then $F(x)$ is the $k+1$ coordinate of $G$, but this integral only has $dx^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^k$.

Comment: try to elucidate by taking $k=1,2,3,...$

Comment: This is how I think this should be the volume of $F$ over $[0,1]^k$. For example, when $k = 1$, this becomes $\int_G dx =$ the arc length of $F$ on $[0,1]$. But I just can't get it right when explicitly calculating it. Could you point out which step did I do wrong?

Comment: @InsultedByMathematics Why do you think that $\int_G dx$ is equal to the arc length of $F$? That is just not true. Using Stokes theorem you can calculate $\int_G dx = x(G(1)) - x(G(0)) = 1$.

Comment: I don't quite see how I can apply Stoke's theorem here. Could you be more specific?

Comment: @InsultedByMathematics $G$ is a curve with edges (i.e. one-dimensional manifold with boundary). Form $dx$ is a de Rham differential of the function $x$. So you can apply Stokes theorem directly.

Comment: I see! So I guess my evaluation of the integral is correct? It's just my intuition failed me?

Comment: @InsultedByMathematics I think it is correct. For example, there is a way of evaluation that gives the same result: you can apply Stokes theorem to your general case $k > 1$ since $dx_1 \wedge \dots \wedge dx_k = d(x_1 dx_2 \wedge \dots \wedge dx_k)$. It will result with an inductive formula, which reduces to the case $k = 1$.

Comment: I see! Thank you very much for your help!